# Laravel импорт данных из Excel

Tags: mysql, laravel, excel, preparedstatement

Вопрос уже не раз задавался в сообществе, но меня интересует детали скорее, чем само решение.
Итак, ситуация рядовая: есть таблицы

- Users (ID, name)
- Cards (ID, number)
- User_cards (user_id, card_id)

Есть форма, в которой выбирается excel файл, в котором две колонки: ФИО, номер карты и таких записей, скажем, 10 000 в этом файле.

А теперь собственно вопрос: как лучше всего реализовать проверки:

1. Пользователь с таким именем существует в таблице Users
2. Карта с таким номером существует в таблице Cards

Я понимаю что это можно сделать через обычные Eloquent

```php
// ищем пользователя по ФИО 
User::where('name', $userName)->first();

// ищем карту по номеру
Card::where('number', $cardNumber)->first();
```

Но. Если бы речь шла о чистом PHP, то я бы использовал Prepared Statement, для уменьшения нагрузки на сервер БД, а так получается очень много однотипных запросов без экономии.

Для парсинга самого excel я использую Laravel Excel. https://laravel-excel.com/
Такую работу я убираю в фон, в Jobs, в очереди, но как работать в Laravel с подготовленными выражениями я все таки не понимаю. В качестве СУБД использую MySQL 5.0.11

Comment: *как лучше всего реализовать проверки* Ну раз формально пополняются три таблицы, то это будет три запроса, куда деваться. А коли так, то самое разумное: создать временную таблицу, загрузить в неё все данные из эксельного файла (который для этого разумнее конвертировать в CSV), добавить всех имеющихся юзеров в таблицу юзеров, игнорируя дубликаты, то же проделать с картами, и затем то же с парами юзер-карта. И всё, собсно. А по одной записи мурыжить - это же бред голимый, даже не берись.

Comment: моя ошибка, я не указал прямо: пользователи и карты уже есть в таблицах соответсвующих. Задача "привязать" карты к пользователям на основании файла Excel

Comment: Это ничего не меняет. Более того, последний коммент (слова о том, что юзеры и карты есть в БД) противоречит вопросу (необходимость реализации проверок говорит о том, что в эксельном файле есть юзеры и/или карты, отсутствующие в БД).

Comment: И, я полагаю, разумно указать используемую СУБД, включая её версию.

Comment: @Akina в файле excel может быть все что угодно, я ведь не могу дать гарантию, что пользователи будут грузить. Про БД вы правы, дополнил

Answer (score 1):

1. Конвертируем XLS/XLSX в CSV и кладём в `secure_file_priv`
2. Создаём временную таблицу (тип и размер данных корректируется в соответствии с данными)

   ```
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp;        
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp ( user VARCHAR(255),
                                 card VARCHAR(16) ) Engine = Memory;
   ```
3. Загружаем данные из CSV

   ```
   LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE temp;
   ```
4. Добавляем отсутствующих юзеров, игнорируем существующих (предполагается, что имеется уникальный индекс `users(name)`)

   ```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO users (name)
   SELECT DISTINCT user
   FROM temp;
   ```
5. Делаем то же с картами (предполагается, что имеется уникальный индекс `cards(number)`)

   ```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO cards (number)
   SELECT DISTINCT card
   FROM temp;
   ```
6. Пополняем таблицу соответствия

   ```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO user_cards (user_id, card_id)
   SELECT u.id, c.id
   FROM users u, temp t, cards c
   WHERE u.name = t.user
     AND c.number = t.card
   ```
7. Если нужно - удаляем временную таблицу

   ```
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp;
   ```

Все запросы можно собрать в одну хранимую процедуру - тогда из Laravel нужно будет только выполнить конвертацию и затем выполнить эту процедуру.

Comment: Изящное решение. Но вопрос: допустим нужно сделать проверки дополнительные (карта есть в БД и она никем не занята), это делать на этапе выборки из временной таблицы получается?

Comment: @Himu У нас нет запроса SELECT в наборе. Но ничто не мешает добавить всё, что требуется.