# Выгрузить большое количество данных в sql таблицу с помощью c#

Tags: c#, sql

Как скоро можно выгрузить большое количество данных в sql таблицу с помощью c#, в моем случае 200 000 рекордов с Excel? Посоветуйте что-то пожалуйста.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982478/229437 Для других СУБД просто адаптировать - средства пакетной загрузки есть во всех практически.

Comment: Уточните, который SQL

Comment: спасибо, я уже решил проблему с помощью SqlBulkCopy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как скоро можно выгрузить большое количество данных в sql таблицу с
>   помощью c#, в моем случае 200 000 рекордов с Excel?

Зависит от многих факторов, так как вы можете вставлять, как 200 000 записей с одной цифровой колонкой, так и данные, где каждая строка содержит бинарный файл в несколько гигов и в этих 2-ух разных сценариях вставка будет ощутимо отличаться по времени.

Так же вы не указали каким сопосбом сейчас осуществляете вставку. Так если вы вставляете по 1 записи, то скорость будет одна, если уже вставляете пакетно, но скорость не удовлетворяет, то проблема в чем-то другом.

Вы не указали СУБД...

Те не менее, любая уважающая себя СУБД имеет API для пакетной загрузки данных.

Например, в Sql Server- это [`BULK INSERT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) и можно без прибегая к C# грузить файлы из CSV. Так же есть и обертка в виде класса [`SqlBulkCopy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8).

В других СУБД должны быть точно такие же средства => читайте документацию по конкретной СУБД.

Если же, в ней отсутствуют способы пакетной загрузки, то ничто вам не мешает руками формировать пакет из вставки N записей:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (f1,f2,f3) VALUES (1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3)
```

В MS SQL, вроде, ограничение на вставку 1000 за раз таким способом.

Так же есть ESF Migration Toolkit-это отдельная утилита, которая быстро выполняется операции по миграции данных и тоже имеет данные из одного источника переместить в другой.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy.помог, не считая выгрузку с Excel, выгрузка с DataTable в таблицу занимает до 4 секунд, это хорошо, спасибо. Но открытие книги Excel (с 200 000 записями) длится до 20 секунд (app.Workbooks.Open(pathFile))